# CSS3 transition effect for hover on AND off

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have made a hover effect for when the mouse hovers over the nav button, however it just pops back into place when the mouse leaves.
I am wondering how to properly achieve the effect of hovering on and off.

I have tried adding the transition code to both a and a:hover, however when I do that there is some weird unwanted transition effect every time I navigate to, or refresh the page.

Here is the code:

```
nav a {
text-decoration: none;
padding: 25px 20px;
transition-property: background color ease-in-out;
transition-duration: 300ms;
transition-timing-function: linear;
}
nav a:hover {
background-color: #28292B;
transition-property: background color ease-in-out;
transition-duration: 300ms;
transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this instead:

```
 nav a {
text-decoration: none;
padding: 25px 20px;
-o-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
transition:.5s  ease-in-out;
}
nav a:hover {
background-color: #28292B;
    color:white;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/cChst/1/)

Simple and easy.:)

Comment: The issue I'm having with some weird animation when I refresh still exists, but I've narrowed it down to only Chrome and only when its on the my server. Confusing I know.
However your answer did help a lot, that is a much better way of doing it!